# java gui without desktop environment

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, swt, gnome

Is it possible to use java gui frameworks (such as Swing, SWT or javaFX) without desktop environment, such as Gnome?

Answer (score 2):

Although I haven't encountered this situation myself, I would suspect that this would be the case where the [`HeadlessException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/HeadlessException.html) would come into play.

The [Javadoc for `HeadlessException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/HeadlessException.html) says the following:

> Thrown when code that is dependent on
>   a keyboard, display, or mouse is
>   called in an environment that does not
>   support a keyboard, display, or mouse.

The `HeadlessException` is thrown by the constructors of various classes that deal with the GUI, such as [`Dialog`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html) and [`JFrame`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#JFrame()), so I would suspect that in non-GUI environments, the `HeadlessException` will be thrown when attempting to use a GUI toolkit.

Comment: I think that the OP would be more interested in the system property that ignores HeadlessException ...

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to do testing, or need to use some of the image manipulation classes on a server, then a virtual framebuffer will work. I'll assume you're running Linux; I've had good luck with [Xvfb](http://www.xfree86.org/4.0.1/Xvfb.1.html).

Comment: I've used Xvfb for some AWT based image manipulation on a server in the past and it worked out fine for that.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `-Djava.awt.headless=true` or `System.setProperty("java.awt.headless","true")` allows using graphics with some [limitations](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/headless/). Drawing into an offscreen buffer works well, as [discussed here](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=1012) in the context of [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) running on a web server.